# CVS Version on RHEL5

Tags: linux, redhat, cvs, rhel, rhel5

Currently I have CVS version 1.11.17 installed on RHEL4 server in my workspace. Now, my company is planning to upgrade to RHEL5.
Is the CVS version compatible with RHEL5, or we'll need to upgrade that too?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

CVS has not changed in years. Development stopped 10 years ago. The cvs versions in RHEL4,5,6,7 will all be compatible.

In general:

- 1.11.x = The latest stable version
- 1.12.x = A newer version that was never declared 'stable' and then development on CVS stopped. In RHEL you will not be given the 1.12.x version. In some other distributions you may be.